# events still firing despite calling removeEventListener

Tags: javascript, events

The event still triggers after the removeEventListener is called (and it is called), I'm not sure why though and my google-fu hasn't been strong enough to solve this (removed code unrelated to the events)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#NewGame').click(function(){
    document.addEventListener('keypress', keyPress, false);
});

var keyPress = function(e) {
    var key = e.key;
    key = key.toLowerCase(key);

    if (!isGameOver) {
        if (currentAnswer.indexOf('_') === -1) {
            isGameOver = WinGame(isGameOver);
        }
        if (numOfGuesses < 1) {
            isGameOver = LoseGame(isGameOver);
        }
    }
}
});

function LoseGame(isGameOver) {

isGameOver = true;
document.removeEventListener('keypress', keyPress, false);

return isGameOver;
}
```

Comment: You're not removing `keyPress` handler from `document`. `keyPress` is a local variable in `ready()`, `LoseGame` can't refer it. `removeEventListener` just fails, you should see an error in the console: "ReferenceError: keyPress is not defined".

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why I didn't notice that in the console before. Is there a way to tag a comment as an answer?